# Store values from an unordered data file

Tags: swift, mapbox, geojson

When you parse / loop through a data file that is unordered, how can I store the values into an object or variable for later use?

The actual file is a GeoJSON file with map coordinates for golf hole features, that has many geographic objects defined in it of 2 types (polygons or points). Below is a small sample:

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "holeno": 19,
        "feature": "teebox"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -1.478163,
              53.869862
            ],
            [
              -1.478122,
              53.869801
            ],
            [
              -1.477888,
              53.869859
            ],
            [
              -1.477927,
              53.869922
            ],
            [
              -1.478163,
              53.869862
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      },
      "id": "0351f53178c564588a506709c7039509"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "holeno": 15,
        "feature": "pastGreen"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -1.472843,
          53.871483
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": "03850283164d2a7a63d1793baebff719"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "holeno": 8,
        "feature": "teebox"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -1.479439,
              53.875594
            ],
            [
              -1.47972,
              53.875493
            ],
            [
              -1.479667,
              53.875434
            ],
            [
              -1.479363,
              53.87554
            ],
            [
              -1.479439,
              53.875594
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      },
      "id": "05a1644f6c7d11db4f802fb14b98b8b3"
    }
],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

I would like to be able to store these into classes, variables or objects for later use / processing. But the unordered structure is causing me problems, specifically around the choice to data type and initialisation.

An array has its own index, starting at 0, and you cannot insert at a random number using the insert(at:) function.

A dictionary only stores a single key-value pair. I have 2 map coordinates per hole, plus a minimum of 3 polygons, but possibly more.

A struct has simpler initialisation, but I will only know 1 property's value at the time I would create each struct. I could use Optional values for each property, but what would be a recommended way to complete the instance's initialisation of all properties? How would I check that an instance for a particular hole has already been previously created?

A class has the same issues as a struct, but more complex regarding initialisation.

I am new to and learning Swift, so have I missed or misinterpreted something with the above data types? Is there a means to accomplish the above I may not have heard of?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `Codable` and `JSONEncoder/Decoder`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encoding_decoding_and_serialization

Comment: @GreatBigBore many thanks. I have started my search around the Codable protocol... Found a decent Youtube video posted by "IBM Data" by a guy from Couchbase about it... https://youtu.be/BI9_v47wKsA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Swift 4]** Based on your Json structure, you have to design your model classes/struct using **Codable**. Based on your sample, I found 4 model structs those are enough to map your json to an object.

First Create **RootModel** struct which will hold another struct say **Feature**:

```
    struct RootModel : Codable {
     let features : [Features]?
     let type : String?

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

     case features = "features"
     case type = "type"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      features = try values.decodeIfPresent([Features].self, forKey: .features)
      type = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)
    }

    }
```

Now you need the **Feature** model struct which will holding **Properties** & **Geometry**:

```
struct Features : Codable {
let type : String?
let properties : Properties?
let geometry : Geometry?
let id : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case type = "type"
    case properties
    case geometry
    case id = "id"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    type = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)
    properties = try Properties(from: decoder)
    geometry = try Geometry(from: decoder)
    id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
}

}
```

Geometry &  Properties struct:

```
struct Properties : Codable {
let holeno : Int?
let feature : String?
----- similar CodingKeys & init----
}

struct Geometry : Codable {
let coordinates : [[[Double]]]?
let type : String?
----- similar CodingKeys & init----
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Features.CodingKeys.self)
    let geoValues = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .geometry)
    type = try geoValues.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)
    if type == "Point" {
        let pointVal = try geoValues.decodeIfPresent([Double].self, forKey: .coordinates)
        let nestedVal = [[pointVal]]
        coordinates = nestedVal as? [[[Double]]]
    } else {
        coordinates = try geoValues.decodeIfPresent([[[Double]]].self, forKey: .coordinates)

    }
}
}
```

Finally, just use the **RootModel** struct as below:

```
let data: Data? = your_json_string.data(using: .utf8)
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let responseModel = try! jsonDecoder.decode(RootModel.self, from: data!)
```

Comment: thanks for the sample code, it is most helpful when trying to apply what I am reading & learning about the `Codable` protocol and being able to put it up against your code as a reference. I am trying to build this up myself (working from inside outwards), and have reached a challenge... Any feature that is of type `"Polygon"` has a triple-nested `[Double]`'s (I don't know why...) but a type `"Point"` simply has a single Array of Double's. How do you differentiate and / or code around this?

Comment: Best if you can make change symmetric type of coordinate in server side, otherwise you have to convert from [Double] -> [[[Double]]]. Please check the updated code inside geometry struct "init".

Comment: Although I can create the content by drawing on a map, I am downloading the resulting GeoJSON file / content from Mapbox, so I have no control of the format. I would prefer to not edit every file I will make, but have a better means of initially parsing it... I found this issue by first of all setting the Geometry.coordinates to be of type `[Double]` - next runtime it complained about seeing an array of items. Is it possible to branch the parsing, 1 for `Points` another for `Polygon`?

Comment: .@Razib (if you're still watching this thread!) Using your style / code, could the `Geometry` struct's `coordinate` property be of type `Any` to get around the 2 different array structures from my downloaded GeoJSON file? So for a "Point" it would only be a `[Double]` but for a "Polygon" it would be a `[[[Double]]]]` ?

Comment: You can't use Any. How about use enum codable like enum GeoType: Codable {case singleDouble([Double]),  case tripleDouble([[[Double]]])
    init(from decoder: Decoder){make condition code} }. In Geometry struct use coordinates = GeoType & init: coordinates = try GeoType.init(from: decoder). I have no idea any other way.